# SQLite3. Странное поведение при создании таблицы.

Tags: sqlite3

```
create table Group(recordId integer primary key, name text);
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Error: near "Group": syntax error
```

Удаляю или добавляю какой-нибудь символ - создает нормально...

Может кто подсказать что не так, или подтвердить такое поведение?

ЗЫ. Юзаю консольную утилиту sqlite3, версия 3.7.9-2, ОС Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group - это ключевое слово, которое зарезервировано для использования в командах. Почитайте: [мануалы](http://www.sqlite.org/search?q=Group)

Comment: Думал все-таки можно создавать таблицы с такими именами.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table [Group] (recordId integer primary key, name text);
```

Так должно работать

Comment: Спасибо, пофиксил просто префиксом для таблиц.

Comment: Тоже не плохой выход)

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, вариант с префиксами выпилил. Вместо этого просто оборачиваю все - и поля, и таблицы - в двойные кавычки.